# Changing the popovercontroller background colour of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverbackgroundview

I am calling a `UITabBarController` and displaying it as a popover, however when the popover is displayed, at each corner there is a little white edge (the views within have a coloured background).

In any other UIPopoverController I would set the class of the view to a .m file and then use the following code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

However I am unable to set a custom class to a `UITabViewController` and so am unable to do this.
I have attempted to set the above code in the individual tabs once they load however this has no impact as they are sub-views of the `UITabViewController`.

Has anyone got a solution for this? I have searched all over for an answer and it is eluding me.

Comment: *Why* can't you subclass `UITabBarController`?

Comment: It does not allow me to, if you attempt to change the class with the drop down it gives you no options to choose from.